# computing hash function for directory in linux

Tags: directory, hashsum

Can we compute hash function(sha1 and md5) for an empty directory or for directory itself in linux?

Comment: Uh, what exactly is the use case? What data would the checksum operate on, in particular?

Answer (score 2):

Sure, you can tarball the file and compute its checksum.

```
tar -c -O directory/ | md5sum
```

If you want the content checksum you can also try

```
find -s somedir -type f -exec md5sum {} \; | md5sum
```

Really depends on what you want to do...

Comment: no we need to compute the empty directories hash function in a particular directory. so it must be automated without help of tarballing them.

Comment: The tar solution is automated. No input necessary. You are trying to compute a hash of content in the directory? or just the directory name?

Comment: just directory name

Comment: Try this, find directory -printf "%H\n" | md5sum

Comment: we shouldn't modify the empty directories. But need to compute the hash function for empty directory name:
for example: if we create a empty directory using touch command and then we need to compute the newly added directory's hash function which is empty. commands in linux only!!

Comment: @SasankSaiSujanAdapa `touch` creates empty files, not directories. Did you mean `mkdir`?